# Only apply changes to Scriptable Object asset on "Save" button click in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

```cs
[CustomEditor(typeof(Test))]
[CanEditMultipleObjects]
public class TestInspector : Editor
{
  public override void OnInspectorGUI()
  {
    serializedObject.Update();

    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("Flag1Enabled"));
    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("Flag2Enabled"));
    
    if(GUILayout.Button("Apply changes"))
    {
      serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
    if(GUILayout.Button("Discard changes"))
    {
      //Assuming what I think this is doing which is reset all unapplied modifications?
      serializedObject.Update();
    }
  }
}
```

The issue I am facing with the above code is that the Inspector UI does not get updated when `Flag1Enabled` or `Flag2Enabled` toggles are interacted with. The UI only gets updated when `serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties()` is called at the end of the `OnInspectorGUI` method which messes with my goal i.e. I only want changes to be applied to the S.O. asset on clicking "Save changes" button.

I also thought of creating a copy of the serialized object and making edits to the duplicate object - maybe this is a/the way but looking for simple solutions.

I'm pretty new to Unity - perhaps, I am making this more complicated that it needs to be?

Answer (score 0):

> //Assuming what I think this is doing which is reset all unapplied modifications?

Yesn't. It is a bit more complicated with editor scripting and serialization. You have to think frame-wise.

Within one call of `OnInspectorGUI` you have

- an asset (in your case ScriptableObject instance) on your disk
- the according current c# class instance (`target`)
- the `serializedObject` which is basically a virtual "in-between" transfer object between the Inspector and the asset
- And then you have the `SerializedProperty`s which as part of the `serializedObject` are also sort of a staging area

Now when you call `serializedObject.Update` you load the current values from the `target` (c# instance) values into the staging `SerializedProperty`.

When you call `ApplyModifiedProperties` it accordingly applies those back to the actual asset and triggers all sort of other secondary functionalities like *dirty*-marking (= saving as Unity only writes assets to disk that are marked as dirty), Undo/Redo etc.

You could of course use some "manual" staging system like e.g. this

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(TestComponent))]
[CanEditMultipleObjects]
public class TestInspector : Editor
{
    bool flag1EnabledValue;
    bool flag2EnabledValue;

    SerializedProperty flag1Enabled;
    SerializedProperty flag2Enabled;

    bool dirty;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        flag1Enabled = serializedObject.FindProperty("Flag1Enabled");
        flag2Enabled = serializedObject.FindProperty("Flag2Enabled");

        serializedObject.Update();

        flag1EnabledValue = flag1Enabled.boolValue;
        flag2EnabledValue = flag2Enabled.boolValue;
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        using (var changeCheck = new EditorGUI.ChangeCheckScope())
        {
            flag1EnabledValue = EditorGUILayout.Toggle(flag1Enabled.displayName, flag1EnabledValue);
            flag2EnabledValue = EditorGUILayout.Toggle(flag2Enabled.displayName, flag2EnabledValue);

            if (changeCheck.changed)
            {
                dirty = true;
            }
        }

        using (new EditorGUI.DisabledScope(!dirty))
        {
            if (GUILayout.Button("Apply changes"))
            {
                flag1Enabled.boolValue = flag1EnabledValue;
                flag2Enabled.boolValue = flag2EnabledValue;
                serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
                dirty = false;
            }

            if (GUILayout.Button("Discard changes"))
            {
                flag1EnabledValue = flag1Enabled.boolValue;
                flag2EnabledValue = flag2Enabled.boolValue;
                dirty = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but this might become quite uncanny in more complex types.